# Swagger Api Docs and Swagger UI not working with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I do have Some Restful webservices which are developed on Spring    `@RestController`   and using Spring5.0.5 . ( This is not a Spring Boot Project )

I am trying to generate API Documentation using Swagger and for that i am trying to use Springfox.

Below are the Changes which i made in the Project :-
Added in Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Created a SwaggerConfig.java Class -

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("package-name"))              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

Note :- I have tried adding/deleting  @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) as well.

AppConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigureAdaptor{

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
}
```

But on using `http://localhost:port/context-root/v2/api-docs` and `http://localhost:port/context-root/v2/swagger-ui.html` I keep getting some Bean initialization exception -

Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootStrapper'.
Please suggest where am i wrong in the implementation.
I have been trying removing and adding few annotations but no success so far.

Error: -

```
DispatcherSer       E   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean  Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error createion bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/WebspherePathforWarfile/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [wsjar:file:C:/webspeherisntalledapp/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/webMVCRequestHandlerProvider.class ] Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception  is org.springframework.beans.factory.NosuchBeandefinitionException : No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>' available :expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.Dependency annotations {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$dogetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda.000000002E7527.getObject(unkown source)
        ......
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
.................
caused by :org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL [wsjar:file:C:/Webspherinstalledapp/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class] : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception  is org.springframework.beans.factory.NosuchBeandefinitionException : No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>' available :expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$dogetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda.000000002E7527.getObject(unkown source)
```

Update  i was able to resolve this error by removing @Configuration annotation from SwaggerConfig.java but now i am in a different issue.

Getting - noHandlerFound No mapping found when i access http://localhost:port/context-root/v2/api-docs

Comment: Post your entire stacktrace so we can see the root cause?